# Omnisharp vscode - Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, omnisharp

I've been having a hard time running `dotnet` commands on an existing dotnet 6 application, on my m1 mac. I seem to have made it worse by downloading the dotnet SDK 6.0.401 in arm64 version, which has caused this error as soon as I open the project in vs code:

> Starting OmniSharp server at 9/25/2022, 4:57:13 PM
> Target: /Users/benjamin/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.sln
>
> OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.401 .
> Path: /Users/benjamin/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-darwin-arm64/.omnisharp/1.39.0-net6.0/OmniSharp.dll
> PID: 59074
>
> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
> file or assembly
> '/Users/benjamin/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-darwin-arm64/.omnisharp/1.39.0-net6.0/OmniSharp.dll'.
> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> File name:
> '/Users/benjamin/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-darwin-arm64/.omnisharp/1.39.0-net6.0/OmniSharp.dll'

I have redownloaded the x86 version and reinstalled C# in vscode extensions but I still get the same error. What should I do?

UPDATE: Ive now successfully run dotnet commands and even ran the app. I still have the same error message when I open vs code though, so I still have the problem but it is not preventing me doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

In my case just reverting the C# vscode extension to version 1.24.4 fixed it.

[Actually, the issue with the version only exists for people with x64 .net sdk installed on an m1 mac.](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5224#issuecomment-1136698373) . Reveerting the C# vscode extension, or downloading the arm64 .net sdk should work (and I reverted the C# vscode extension).

Answer (score 2):

Would you by accident have the setting `omnisharp.useModernNet` set to false? Or have any `omnisharp.` setting with `mono` or `path` or `sdk` in it?

If so, try removing all of them. And maybe setting `omnisharp.useModernNet` explicitly to `true` (it should be the default).

If this fails, try:

- Removing and reinstalling the extension
- Setting `"omnisharp.path": "latest"`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, I installed .NET 6.0.401 from Microsoft packages but the issue still happened.

It turned out VSCode was using x64 version which was installed previously, not arm64 one. It seems the installer didn't relocate my dotnet command. I re-create the dotnet link to correct arm64 one and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. I hope this solution works.

My solution was

Extension -> Settings (wheel symbol) -> Install Another Version... -> 1.24.4

Basically, I downgraded the version of the C# extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors using dotnet 6.0.x SDK and VSCode on my M1 Mac. VSCode would not run the C# debugger with the same error. I checked in the File > About VSCode menu item and was running the x64 version of VSCode. I uninstalled VSCode and then re-installed with the universal installer and it now shows the Universal installation. This resolved the error for me.

Comment: Cool, good catch. This is mine. I think the relevant bit is OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0 which seems like the arm64 version which should be correct for M1 mac.

`Version: 1.71.2
Commit: 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7
Date: 2022-09-14T21:07:15.900Z
Electron: 19.0.12
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I had the same problem with dotnet x86 and x64 incompatibility. I have 32-bit vscode installed, which installs `ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2-win32-ia32`, which downloads that x86 version of Omnisharp. But I had `C:\Program Files\dotnet` before `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` on my PATH, so when the vscode extension ran `dotnet` the x64 version was found, which failed.

The fix was to move `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` to be before the x64 dotnet on my PATH, either temporarily on the command line, or in the system environment variables.